# How to change the image of a selected cell of a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to use this code, but it's not working:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
printf("Selected View index=%d",indexPath.row);

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_s.png"]];
//[self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

How do I change the `UIImage` of selected `UICollectionViewCell` in a `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did using this

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_seat.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_s.png"]];
return cell;
}
```

got help from [link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-collection-view-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Please give example how to use it.